# Error when using function: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Tags: mysql, sql, function

In my MySQL database I have defined a function called isUserVerified that return the status of a user.

I am trying to use the function in a SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    id, isUserVerified(id) AS verification
FROM
    users
```

But I get the following error:

> ## 1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

This is my function definition:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE isVerified VARCHAR(10);

    SELECT 
        users.profile_verification, users.id
    INTO 
        isVerified
    FROM 
        users 
    WHERE 
        users.id = user_id;
    
    RETURN isVerified;
END
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you are missing showing us the function definition...

Comment: phpMyAdmin is just a web frontend to query a MySQL database. You are using MySQL. I have retagged your question and replaced the other usage of phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are selecting *two* columns but inserting into only one variable.  Presumably, you intend:

```
SELECT users.profile_verification
INTO isVerified
```